# How to pass a list from C# to Ironpython as input parameter of a function

Tags: c#, marshalling, ironpython

I have a *Python* script which I use in my *C#* code (*Ironpython*), which works fine. So additionally I'd like to add a list as input parameter for my function in the *Python* script.

I get some strings from a C# WinForm which I have formatted like Python code:

```
string code = "list [a, b, c, d]";
```

My additional C# Code:

```
ScriptSource source = m_engine.CreateScriptSourceFromString(code);
dynamic script = m_engine.ExecuteFile(@"path to my file");
dynamic function = script.UpdateElements(source);
```

But then I get the following exception:

> iteration over non-sequence of type ScriptSource

In my Python file I have a function like this (where source is a list):

```
def UpdateElements(source):
   #do some stuff
```

So my question: how can I pass a list of strings from C# as input to my function in the Python script?

Comment: Could you extend your sample to show what you are doing with *source* in *UpdateElements*? Your exception is probably caused by an iteration like `for s in source:`...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Having a list of strings as

```python
var code = "['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']";
```

You can execute this list literal source to retrieve an IronPython list:

```python
dynamic result = source.Execute();
```

This list can be used to invoke the function:

```python
dynamic function = script.UpdateElements(result);
```

As an alternative (if the literal string list is just a workaround and you have the actual values in some other form) you could also provide a .NET collection to your IronPython function and be fine for many scenarios:

```python
var data = new[] { "a", "b", "c", "d" };
var engine = Python.CreateEngine();
dynamic script = engine.ExecuteFile(@"script.py");
dynamic function = script.UpdateElements(data);
```